# GAM (mgcv) - create new variable or use interaction

Tags: r, modeling, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

For this purpose, say I'm fitting a gam-model. I have a response `Y` that I want to predict with two continuous covariates, `A` and `B`. On their own, I don't expect A and B to predict Y that much (they might though). On the other hand, combined there should be more predictive power.

Now, my question is this, what is the difference between creating, say a new variable `Z`, which is the fraction $\frac{A}{B}$ (could do the product as well) or creating an interaction term without modifying A and B. I have seen examples of both but no real discussion/motivation which way to go.

Is it because it's obvious which way I should go and I fail to grasp it or are both possible? I have leaned heavily towards doing `Z` but maybe that's a fault by me?

$Y = f_{1}(Z_{i})$

$Y = f_{1}(A_{i}B_{i})$

Comment: Your first suggestion is more restrictive than the second. If you don't have a scientific justification for option 1 I'd go with option 2 and use an interaction smoother.

Comment: @Roland Thx  - it was exactly the restrictiveness I was angling for. In this case there is probably a scientific reason to create Z (in the fractional case). Atleast the fraction is  something that is interpretable in the real world and how we pre-model would think they should be combined, if we're combining them.